# Horizontal planes not detected in Iphone SE

Tags: ios, xcode, arkit

I have been working on Arkit applications these days and have tested many of these applications using Iphone 8 and Iphone X.

I have downloaded a project from Github - https://github.com/max6363/measure-using-ARKit-iOS11.

Though, in the project read me section, the developer mentioned that it is compatible with IPhone SE, my mobile is not able to detect any horizontal planes and as a result of this, I am not able to create any point in the space.

Could someone please let me know regarding this.
I would like to know,if I need to make any changes to the project.

Thanks in advance!